# SQL calculate buckets based on equal deciles from range

Tags: sql, oracle

How could I go about using a function to calculate which bucket a value falls into? Here is an example below of what I'm trying to get to.

Say you have a table with five values - [0, 4, 6, 20, 50]

The range of these values would be 50 (50 - 0) and if you split it into 10 equal buckets, each bucket would be 5.

Thus, the output would show:

```
Value     Bucket #
0         1
4         1
6         2
20        4
50        10
```

Where bucket 1 is 0 - 5, bucket 2 is 6 - 10, etc.

Comment: You do realize that your buckets are **not** equal, don't you? 0-5 has **six** values in it, not five. Other than that, you may want to take a look at `width_bucket`: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions214.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like simple arithmetic on the min and max value:

```
select t.*,
       (1 + floor((value - min_value) * 10 / (max_value - min_value + 1))) as bucket
from (select t.*, min(value) over () as min_value, max(value) over () as max_value
      from t
     ) t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1fe27aadeb5455b3285638badd36f9f8) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Yep, that'll do it. Thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 3):

This is **exactly** what the analytic function `width_bucket` is for:

```
select value, width_bucket(value, min_value, max_value + 1, 10) bucket
from   (
         select t.*, min(value) over () min_value, max(value) over () max_value
         from   t
       )
;
```

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions214.htm

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful to know! That's a bit cleaner than doing the calculation.